# How can I edit multiple files in Vim?

Tags: linux, command-line, vim, files

I know I can open multiple files with `vim` by doing something like `vim 2011-12*.log`, but how can I switch between files and close the files one at a time?

Also, how can I tell the file name of the current file that I'm editing?

Comment: Related: [gvim -p limit of opened tabs?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30665/9689)

Answer (score 258, accepted):

First of all, in vim you can enter <kbd>:</kbd> (colon) and then help `help`, ala `:help` for a list of self-help topics, including a short tutorial. Within the list of topics, move your cursor over the topic of interest and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> and that topic will be opened.

A good place for you to start would be the topic

```
|usr_07.txt|  Editing more than one file
```

Ok, on to your answer.

After starting vim with a list of files, you can move to the next file by entering `:next` or `:n` for short.
`:wnext` is short for write current changes and then move to next file; `:wn` is an abbreviation for `:wnext`.

There's also an analogous `:previous`, `:wprevious` and `:Next`. (Note that `:p` is shorthand for `:print`. The shorthand for `:previous` is `:prev` or `:N`.)

To see where you are in the file list, enter `:args` and the file currently being edited will appear in `[]` (brackets).

Example:

```
vim foo.txt bar.txt
:args
```

result:

```
[foo.txt] bar.txt
```

Comment: You can also do :rew to get back to the first file. :e# swaps between 2 files. :n! goes to next file without writing. Also look at :set autowrite.

Comment: With respect to multiple _buffers_ / _windows_ / _tabs_ also see StackOverflow's [How to effectively work with multiple files in Vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664/how-to-effectively-work-with-multiple-files-in-vim) and [Using Vim's tabs like buffers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102384/using-vims-tabs-like-buffers).

Comment: I found chapter 22 "Finding the file to edit" very useful as well. It goes over using the directory explorer to edit the files you want.

Comment: Consider linking to usr_07.txt: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_07.html

Comment: @Kowh, also `:wN` is shorthand for write and open previous file 

Answer (score 96):

you can open another file while vim is open with `:tabe filename` and to switch to the other file you type `:tabn` or `:tabp` for next and previous accordingly.

The keyboard shortcuts **gT** and **gt** can also be used to switch tabs when you are not in editing mode (i.e. not in insert, replace etc modes). On some systems <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> also allow tab-switching, but this does not always work (for example, it won't work in the OS X terminal 'out of the box').

And you can see the filename at the top of the vim app.

Comment: This. Also open files in tabs with:
`vim -p file1 file2`

Comment: AMAZE! I'd never come across this before, despite having used vim for years. This changes **everything**.

Comment: Note that tabs are not intended to work with multiple files. They are intended to work with multiple **layouts**. See [article](https://joshldavis.com/2014/04/05/vim-tab-madness-buffers-vs-tabs/).

Comment: Aside:  If you're already in vim and want to add another file, you can use:  `:argadd filename` and then `:next` to it.  Likewise, you can use `:argdel filename` to remove one of the files in edit.

Comment: Also generally available if you use the tab approach: `:tabnew xyz`, `:Texplore` for selecting a file to open (and `:Hexpl`, `:Vexpl`...), `:tabn3` for e.g. going to the third tab.  I've read the linked article in a comment above a few times over the years, and remain unconvinced that I shouldn't use tabs this way :)

Answer (score 59):

Commands to switch between buffers:

```
:bf            # Go to first file.
:bl            # Go to last file
:bn            # Go to next file.
:bp            # Go to previous file.
:bw            # Close file.
```

`:help buffer` to find more information

To know filename use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>,`:file` or `:f`

Comment: `:bw` close file haha. Don't forget to read the help for `:bw` where it says that you should only use it if you know what you're doing. It's not a big deal, but unless you want to wipe out all of the marks and information about the file, better use `:bd` or `:q` like a normal person

Comment: More info on `:bw` in case you are curious: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2212/what-bad-things-can-happen-if-i-use-bwipeout

Answer (score 39):

Another option apart from the answers given, is to split the window with:

```
:sp
:vsp
```

`:vsp` is for vertical split. Then use `Ctrl+W <ARROW_KEYS>` to move in panes.

Comment: You can use `:vs` instead of `:vsp`

Comment: Or even just `Ctrl+W, v` for vertical split and `Ctrl+W, s` for horizontal split.

Comment: I have been using `CTRL+W` for years and recently I do a lot of VI editing inside web pages. Every single time, I type the command without even thinking and ... whammmm ... browser tab is GONE! I keep forgetting. I really need to learn a new shortcut.

Answer (score 22):

```
:n -> Move to next file
:N -> Move to previous file
```

Answer (score 16):

I asked a similar question at superuser,

[*"How to copy and paste between different bash windows and files opened with VI?"*](https://superuser.com/questions/297755/unix-how-to-copy-and-paste-between-different-bash-windows-with-files-opend-wit)

The answer to my question was you can't, but you can open two files in one bash window using VIM's `:split` command:

1. Open a file with `$ vim file1`, open a second file within VIM using `:split file2` command.
2. Or, use `$ vim -o file1 file2` from bash.
3. Switch between files--toggle active file--in VIM with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>.
4. An example operation then is copy (or yank) in file1 <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>, switch (3), then paste (or put) <kbd>p</kbd> contents into file2.
5. Everything else is normal when either window is active, thus `:q` quits and `:q!` force quits.

My bash is black and white, so the file name of each screen is styled as a reversed 'selected' line with the file name cited there.

Woot!

Comment: Is there an option like number 2 that lets you open multiple files from bash and split them vertically or horizontally, except one of those windows is the current terminal? I know I can do something similar similar from within Vim with the :terminal command, but I would like to be able to do it from bash.

Answer (score 14):

I find the most convenient method of editing multiple files is by using tabs. You can open multiple files in separate tabs via the command line like so:

```
vim -p file1.txt file2.txt
```

Or if you already have vim open, you can open a new file in a new tab like so:

```
:tabe file2.txt
```

Once you have the tabs open, use `gt` to view the next tab and `gT` to view the previous tab.

You can also jump to the first tab with `1gt`, the second tab with `2gt`, etc.

You can close tabs using `:tabc`

Finally you can move the current tab to the `n`th location with `:ntabm` where `n` is any number greater than or equal to `0`.

Answer (score 7):

```
argadd a/b c/d e/f
```

`argadd ...` will add all files to args, and also to `:ls` / `:buffers` and allow you to edit them.

---

See `:h arglsit` & `:h argedit` & `:h argsd`

---

Also, you can perform certain actions only on args with `:argdo ...`, and you can start afresh with your args by doing `:argsd*`.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of way to do so. The first one, maybe the less convenient, is to call `vim` with the files you want to edit - create:

```
vim first_file second_file ...
```

It calls the two files in two buffers. To switch from a file to another, please use `:n` and `:N`. To list the files you are editing, `:args` will do the job. `:help buffer` will help you more on this.

---

This should answer your question. But here are more information:

There is a way to edit your files in a more convenient way by splitting your console screen using **vim**. To do this, open two frames with `:split` (`:sp`) or `:vsplit` (`:vs`) while using **vim**. Then navigate in these frames by using the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>. You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> + the arrow or the key (<kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>L</kbd>) corresponding to the next frame. When this is done, edit the file you want with `:e file_name`. `:help opening-window` will help you more on this.

Now, if you'd like to see the differences between files, use the `-d` argument or call the **vimdiff** program (it is the same) with the corresponding files. `:help diff` will help you more on this.

```
vim -d first_file second_file ...
```

Please let me know if you have some issue.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use split windows - both horizontal and vertical - to edit multiple files.

I use tmux to manage those windows more easily

https://tmux.github.io/
"What is a terminal multiplexer? It lets you switch easily between several programs in one terminal, detach them (they keep running in the background) and reattach them to a different terminal. And do a lot more. See the manual."

Example: Looking at files or running tests on the right, editing test and source files on the left: [image]

Answer (score 0):

`:e #(filename)` to toggle between two opened files

`:p` for previous file

`:n` for next file

Comment: Welcomme to U&L, this hardly add anything to other answer posted years ago.