# gvim -p limit of opened tabs?

Tags: command-line, vim, files, configuration

When I run :

```
gvim -p *.xyz
```

I find that not all files are opened in tabs.

It feels, like a kind of tab limit?

But ! When I try to open unopened with :

```
:tabnew
```

it is opened next to previous tabs - it works !

How to make `gvim -p ...` to open all files without need of opening those above limit manually with `:tabnew` ?

Btw. Is this limit somewhere written ? Possible to be configured?

Comment: Related: [How can I edit multiple files in VIM?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27586/9689)

Comment: In my experience, only a certain number of tabs are _visible_ on the screen at a given time, but they're all there (just off screen).  Could that be the case?  What happens if you do a `:tabprev` from your first tab?

Comment: It is not that. I know `:tabprev` `:tabnext`. There are not there. There are `10` tabs maximum when I open with `gvim -p`. If I want more I need to add them manually with : `:tabnew`. Problem is present in `vim -p` as well.

Comment: As I haven't (recently) experienced this 10-tab phenominon, I decided to look at my (short) vimrc and found something that might work... see my answer.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Put this in your `.vimrc` (usually located at `~/.vimrc`):

```
set tabpagemax=100
```

Comment: I really need to get this committed into my dotfiles because I forget about it every time I'm on a new machine and wanting to edit a bunch of files in tabs and I only get 8-10 the first pass and doing `:next` a bunch of times to go through all the buffers that weren't opened in tabs is terribly annoying.