# :n and :N not working when opening files with

Tags: vim, editors

Okay so I have already gone through [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27586/how-can-i-edit-multiple-files-in-vim).

So I know you can edit multiple files in VIM if you open them up in the following way:

```
vim file1 file2
```

and you can change files using `:n` and `:N`.

**But what if I wanted open up a new file using `:edit` and still use `:n` and `:N`.**

So lets say we open a file in VIM using :

```
vim file1
```

and I am working on this file and I have to open up another file now called `file2`

**Now `:n` and `:N` no longer work.**

Why is that ?

**I want to be able to use `:n` and `:N` after opening the file.** Any way I can do that ?

Seems easy but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Your question is quite confusing, why isn't just `:e file2` working?

Comment: @T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM Try doing `:n` or `:N` after opening using `:e file2` and let me know if they work.

Comment: `:e #` works to go back to the last file. why `:n` ??? please clarify, step by step, what you're trying to do.

Comment: @T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM Yes but I want to use `:n`. Why can't I use that ? Why can't I get the same consistent behaviour ? Why use a different command ? I don't want to use `:e #`

Comment: @T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM Open up any file in VIM using `vim file1` and then try to edit another file. You edit it via `:e` as you said, BUT if you use `:e` you can't use `:n` for navigation. This does not make sense. That is what I am trying to do.

Comment: @T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM Hope this clarifies the issue.

Comment: It's still too deep for me, sorry. You can use `:n` and `:N` after `:e #`.

Comment: @T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM Well it doesn't for me. I get `Only One file to edit.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:argadd file2
```

You can find more info collected together at [How can I edit multiple files in VIM?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27586/how-can-i-edit-multiple-files-in-vim)

Comment: YES this is what I was looking for. This exact command is not in link btw. Thanks.